# Print Screen in AWesome WM

Tags: shortcut-keys, awesome

I'm trying to make it so I can do a screen shot with with the PrintScrn button in Awesome WM. I found an [ImageMagick script with keybinding in the Wiki](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Screenshots), but I'm not able to make it work. The script works if I call it in the command line. What I can't wrap my mind around is what exactly the keybinding is supposed to be doing with the script. Pulled from the Wiki:

Script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 timestamp="$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)"
 targetbase="$HOME/capscr"
 mkdir -p $targetbase
 [ -d $targetbase ] || exit 1
 import -window root $targetbase/$timestamp.png
```

Keybinding:

```
 -- bind PrintScrn to capture a screen
  awful.key(
     {},
     "Print",
     function()
         awful.util.spawn("capscr",false)
    end
  )
```

I assume the "capscr" in the Lua code is calling the script? (The script is saved by the same name in my /home folder; specifically ~/.bin like it says in the Wiki). If not, do I need to do something else to the script and/or Lua code and/or ??? to make the two see each other? I've also tried putting the path of the script in the code to see if that worked, and nothing.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you need make it executable. 
Then move it to /bin directory (you need root-rights):

```
$chmod +x capscr
$sudo mv ./capsrc /bin
```

I also recomend to you to edit capscr file, for example mine:

```
#!/bin/bash
timestamp="$(date +%d.%m.%Y"_shot_"%H:%M:%S)"
targetbase="$HOME/Pictures/screenshots"
mkdir -p $targetbase
[ -d $targetbase ] || exit 1
import -window root -quality 98 $targetbase/$timestamp.png
```